# Is there a way to signalize an object its successful deserialization?

Tags: .net-3.5, netdatacontractserializer

I'm using `NetDataContractSerializer`. After successfully deserializing an object, is there a way to tell the object to finish its construction? I'm thinking along the lines of:

```
[DataContract]
class Foo
{
    [DataMember]
    int i;

    [SerializationCompletedEvent]
    void SerializationCompleted ()
    {
        i = i + 7;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it out myself by now.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.ondeserializedattribute.aspx

Someone missed an easy 15 points I guess?